# SQL using count, error "cannot convert * to int"

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to check the existence of a record in my database using the following function

```
alter function [dbo].[verClientUniq](@cid varchar(2))
returns int
begin
    declare @nr int

    select @nr = count(*) 
    from Clients
    where clientId = @cid;

    return @nr
end
```

When I execute it inside my procedure, I get the error that on line 8 of procedure "varchar '*' can't be converted to int."

Where does this happen? How to fix it?

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure verClientUniq, Line 8
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '*' to data type int.

I'm calling the function this way:

```
exec @isUnique = verClientUniq @cid;
```

Comment: I assume that it is sql server code and it is syntactically valid. What is exact error message?

Comment: I've wrote the exact error message right there Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '*' to data type int.

Comment: Your function is at least missing an `AS` but can you show how you are calling this function in your stored procedure? (Also, you hadn't written the exact error message until you edited the question after Hamlet asked.)

Comment: exec @isUnique = verClientUniq @cid; and isUnique is an int

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it would be the same thing if I wrote it with my own words. My bad, edited.

Comment: @AaronBertrand `AS` is optional

Comment: Shouldn't your call be `SELECT @isUnique = dbo.verClientUniq(@cid);`? What is the value of `@cid` when it fails? What is the data type of `Clients.clientId`?

Comment: I can add more details if needed, I just don't know what else would be usefull

Comment: @Hamlet That's fine, but why would you ever intentionally exclude it? To save 2 characters of typing? I think this is the first time in my ~20 year career I've ever seen anyone leave it out.

Comment: You are also right, the clientId was int and I was trying to pass it as varchar. I left it out cause I'm new to sql and while I do use as in stored procedures, I didn't know I should write it in functions too

Comment: @AaronBertrand I never exclude them, but the code still syntactically correct :)

Comment: @Hamlet It would also be syntactically correct if it were all on one line, that doesn't mean it is better that way.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are right again ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `clientId` is of type `int` when you passing `@cid` as `varchar(2)` which SQL Server tries to convert to `int` in `WHERE` clause.